# Type checking class (not instance of class) extends another class

Tags: typescript

Given the class below:

```
class BaseClass {}
```

I want to create another class which extends this class, i.e.:

```
class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass {}
```

I then want to pass the `ExtendedClass` as an argument to another function (**not** an instance of an `ExtendedClass`, but the class itself!), and type check this by ensuring the `ExtendedClass` extends `BaseClass`.

This doesn't work:

```
function helloClass (c: BaseClass) {}
```

because `c: BaseClass` denotes that `c` should be an **instance** of a `BaseClass` (or something which extends a `BaseClass`) - but not a class which extends `BaseClass` itself.

Is this at all possible within TypeScript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can represent classes like this: `{ new(): BaseClass }`.

Or in an example:

```
interface BaseClassConstructor<T extends BaseClass> {
    new (): T;
}

class BaseClass {
    str: string;
}

class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass { }

function fn<T extends BaseClass>(ctor: BaseClassConstructor<T>) {

}

fn(BaseClass); // fine
fn(ExtendedClass); // fine

class A {
    prop: any;
}

fn(A);  // error
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20BaseClassConstructor%3CT%20extends%20BaseClass%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%20()%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20BaseClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20str%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ExtendedClass%20extends%20BaseClass%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20fn%3CT%20extends%20BaseClass%3E(ctor%3A%20BaseClassConstructor%3CT%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afn(BaseClass)%3B%20%2F%2F%20fine%0D%0Afn(ExtendedClass)%3B%20%2F%2F%20fine%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afn(A)%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20error))